# Find the range of $ f(x)=x^2 +\frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

Tags: functions

I know the range is $[1,\infty)$. I am taking $ x^2 = z , z \ge 0$
then making a quadratic in $z$, i.e.,
$$ z^2 + z(1-y) + 1-y =0.$$
Now since the roots are greater are than zero there sum and products will be greater than zero with
discriminant $\ge 0$.
For $C/A>0$
$$1-y>0,$$
$$y < 1.$$
I do not know what is happening here.

Comment: hint: $$f(x)={\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \right)}^2+1$$

Comment: @albusdumbledore I definitely miscalculated, my apologies

Comment: @abiessu no problem!

Comment: Why are the roots greater than zero?

Comment: You say "the roots are positive" - are you sure? A positive root turns into $x^2\gt 0$ and two real solutions for $x$. A negative root for $z$ may exist and simply give no real solutions for $x$. Don't forget you have a quartic in $x$ which you are reducing to a quadratic in $z$, so each solution for $z$ will correspond to two for $x$.

Comment: @MarkBennet Exactly! The hypothesis that roots are $> 0$ is incorrect in the first place, leading to an absurd conclusion.

Comment: @MarkBennet thanks got your point

Comment: but if negative root exist then x^2 = -k . where k>0

Comment: then x is a complex number but we are told to treat every function as real valued function

Comment: @AshishKumar Just because there are roots of no interest to your problem, doesn't mean they aren't roots of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \ge 2$$ by the AM-GM inequality. Hence, $$f(x) = x^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}  - 1 \ge 1$$
i.e. $$f(x) \ge 1$$
Hence the range is $[1,\infty)$. To show that all values in $[1,\infty)$ are attained, first observe that $f(0) = 1$. Also, as $x\to\infty$, $f(x)\to\infty$. All values between $1$ and $\infty$ are attained since $f$ is continuous.

---

*Comments on OP's approach:* No, the roots are not all greater than zero. See @MarkBennet's comment for details. Since you start with an absurd hypothesis, you reach an absurd conclusion, i.e. $y< 1$.

You have put $x^2 = z$, to get $z^2 + za + a = 0$ for $a = 1-y$. Suppose the roots of this quadratic equation in $z$ are $z_1$ and $z_2$. Then, $z_1 + z_2 = -a$ and $z_1z_2 = a$. Clearly, the sum and product of the roots have opposite signs. If the sum is positive, and the product is negative, then one of the two roots has to be negative. If the sum is negative, and the product is positive, then both roots must be negative. In either case, at least one of the roots of $z^2 + za + a = 0$ is negative.

Clearly, this **contradicts** your assumption that both roots are greater than zero.

**Why is at least one root negative?** The equation you started with is a fourth-degree equation, if you look carefully. You'd expect four roots, real or complex. However, the graph of $f(x)$ below suggests that for every fixed $y$, i.e. for every horizontal line, the graph of $f(x)$ intersects the horizontal line at either $0$ points, or $2$ points (there is a repeated root at $(0,1)$, so this comes in the $2$ points case too). Hence, **at least two of the four roots** of the equation $y = f(x)$ are **not real**. Hence, at least one of the roots of the equation in $z$ must be negative (justifying that both roots are not positive, as you had incorrectly assumed).

[image]

Comment: well i konw a.m g.m inequality but this thing never crossed my mind , brilliant use of the tool

Comment: i still dont know how x^2 gives a negative value if x is a real number

Comment: that is bothering me

Comment: please help me out there

Comment: because i replaced x^2 by z

Comment: Yes thats it that cleared my confusion , now i am in heaven just beacuse of you :)

Answer (score 1):

OP needs to ask for reality of the roots of the quadratic equation: $z^2+z(1-y)+(1-y)=0,$
namely $B^2 \ge 4AC \implies (1-y)^2\ge 4 (1-y) \implies  y\le -3 ~or~ y\ge 1$. Since $y=f(x)>0.$ So we choose only $y\ge 1$ and hence the correct range as $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: @Z Ahmed thanks

Answer (score 0):

The map $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb R$ (as a sum of continuous maps). Clearly, $f(x)\geqslant 1$, since we are adding non-negative quantities.

Now let $M>1$ and $x>M$. Then
$$x^2 + \frac{1}{1+x^2}> M^2 + \frac{1}{1+x^2}>M.$$
Thus, $f$ is unbounded. The range is $[1,\infty)$ by the intermediate value theorem.